# Problem Executing Vacuum command in sqlite3 on iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I found this snippet for executing a vacuum of an sqlite3 db but it doesn't work.

can anyone tell me what is wrong with it.

```
sqlite3_exec(dataBase, "VACUUM;", 0, 0);
```

Thanks...

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? It doesn't vacuum? It gives an error message? Something else?

Comment: found a solution it needed an extra parameter....  however it takesa while and locks the database so that's another problem i will have to deal with...

Comment: Vacuum can definitely be slow with a large fragmented database, since it's going to reorder a lot of the data in the file. You shouldn't need to use this call in modern versions of sqlite, since autovacuum will do the cleanup incrementally. Check the sqlite.org docs.

Comment: @Jens Alfke - Auto-vacuum does not defragment the database nor repack individual database pages the way that the VACUUM command does. In fact, because it moves pages around within the file, auto-vacuum can actually make fragmentation worse. see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum). Auto-vacuum is really just for saving space but not for improving database performance by making individual tables and indexes contiguous like the vacuum command does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here's the solution to make the vacuum command work.

```
if(sqlite3_exec(dataBase, "VACUUM;", 0, 0, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Vacuumed DataBase");
}
```

that makes the command work however the app is locked out of the database while it runs.